# In Excel 2007, link to a SQL Server DB with the data connection not possible

Tags: sql-server, excel-2007, database-connection

I have data in a SQL Server 2008 db and I want to get the reporting in Excel.
I have created view for that and I want to link them to Excel using the Data / Connection tool available in Excel 2007.
When I do the import in Excel from the SQL Server on the server machine (ie, where the SQL Server is running) everything is fine and I can refresh manually or automatically (which is what I'm looking for).
But when I try to refresh (or do the link) from an other machine it does not work: I have the following message " [DNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQLServer does not exist or access denied "
The TCP IP protocol is available on the server and a telnet on the port 1433 is working.

So I don't know what could be the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding: namedPipe=true to the connection string.

Can you connect via any other method from the client machine i.e. using SQL Server Tools?  Establish whether it is Excel or general connectivity issue first.

Comment: As I was looking for a way to find the namedPipe I found that the service SQL Server Browser need to be up and running in order to get the connection from an other computer.